# Css styles not applying`

Tags: css

I tried but I cannot figure out why my style is not being applied.

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<title>Document</title>
<style>
#contact
 {
padding: 2em 0;
height: 70em;
width: 100%;
color:red;
 }
#contact h1
 {
text-align: center;
color:red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id"contact">
    <div>
        <h1>Contact us</h1>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a small example, I tried but none of them are being applied.

Comment: id = contact ..see  mising equal

Comment: [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). Use it.

Comment: First please learn how to format code. A very first step in learning something which is very useful.

Comment: Mark the answer immediately or wait for N no of downvotes.

Comment: I think this question should be close as it won't helpful for SO users..only increasing the spam on site.

Comment: @Leothelion yes close as typographical issue.

Comment: what the..this question got 2 upvote..damn.. People please use your dv carefully.

Comment: @Leothelion it has downvotes, not upvotes haha.

Comment: @Leothelion I am shocked.

Comment: Please check he got 2 uv and 4 dv

Comment: @C0dekid.php It earlier had 4 downvotes. You are late here. Haha

Comment: Ohh I see! Need to get more reps then.. :P @Leothelion

Comment: Voted to close. Such a poor question, I must say.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `=` sign after 'id':

`<div id="contact">`

Answer (score 0):

First, modify this: 'div id="contact"'

Comment: And then..? What should he do next?

Comment: Next, OP should close this question in sake for decreasing the spam on SO XD...